# Auth0 query param (q=) not returning expected results

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, auth0

I am using auth0 management api v2 with .net core 2.1 to fetch uses's logs. Now i want to fetch only success and failed logs and for that my url is:

```
{domain}/api/v2/users/{user_id}/logs?q=type:s type:f&page=1&per_page=10&include_totals=true
```

But this url just returning 10 records, doesn't matter whether they are succeeded logs or failed logs. I have also tried chaning q=type:s only but even that didn't work. Also q=type:\"s\" is not working. other query params are working fine. So I want to know what am I doing wrong? What is the correct syntax?

Update:

By exploring management api docs. I have realized that user log api doesn't accept query param (q=). So is there any way to add search by type criteria in user logs?